Automation anywhere A360, excel as an database
I am working with excel as an database functionality of AA360, came accross a case where I have to insert data into excel using DB query, if only the value is not existing in the sheet to inserted.
Here are the queries I have tried
Insert into [STEP2$$] ([Vorhaben],[verteilt an],[E K Z],[Alle Stellungnahmen da?]) values (SELECT ('$RecSqlDataset[0]$', '$RecSqlDataset[3]$', '$RecSqlDataset[8]$', '$RecSqlDataset[17]$') where not exists (Select [Vorhaben],[verteilt an],[E K Z],[Alle Stellungnahmen da?] from [STEP2$$] where [Vorhaben] = '$RecSqlDataset[0]$'))

Insert into [STEP2$$] ([Vorhaben],[verteilt an],[E K Z],[Alle Stellungnahmen da?]) values ('$RecSqlDataset[0]$', '$RecSqlDataset[3]$', '$RecSqlDataset[8]$', '$RecSqlDataset[17]$') where (Select [Vorhaben] from [STEP2$$]) not in '$RecSqlDataset[0]$

Insert into [STEP2$$] ([Vorhaben],[verteilt an],[E K Z],[Alle Stellungnahmen da?]) values ('$RecSqlDataset[0]$', '$RecSqlDataset[3]$', '$RecSqlDataset[8]$', '$RecSqlDataset[17]$') Where (Select Count([Vorhaben]) from [STEP2$$] where [Vorhaben]='xyz') = 0

I am able to run the 1st part of query successfully Insert into [STEP2$$] ([Vorhaben],[verteilt an],[E K Z],[Alle Stellungnahmen da?]) values (SELECT ('$RecSqlDataset[0]$', '$RecSqlDataset[3]$', '$RecSqlDataset[8]$', '$RecSqlDataset[17]$')
Here Vorhaben is the column in both the input and output file.
It is getting error as syntax error in the command.
I am trying to get the correct syntax for the query.

May be you can try an alternative approach.
First run a SELECT query to check if the value (e.g.Vorhaben) already exists in the Excel file:
Select [Vorhaben] from [STEP2$$] where [Vorhaben] = '$RecSqlDataset[0]$'

Store this in a variable (e.g.recordExist) and then do a conditional check before inserting data.
If recordExist is not Empty then Insert the data.
